# What does “sick spots” mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

This is coming from Charlie and Cardi B on BBC1 radio show:

> Charlie - Would you rather have a night out with me or Offset?
>   Cardi B - With my man (Offset)
>   Charlie - Come on, man! I know London better than Offset, **I can show you all sick spots**.

What does “sick spots” mean?

Comment: Please read through [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4799#4799) to get some tips on how to format your questions.

Answer (score 2):

"Sick" is very informal, current, young people's slang for "good", "exciting", "fun", etc.

[Inverted meanings: sick, bad, and wicked](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/05/05/inverted-meanings-sick/)

Comment: Also used in the same way in the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

And a **spot** is a place, like a bar, pub, club.

> London has some really sick tea-rooms, bro.